How to refresh the data in an embedded Power BI Report Server Report
We have an on-premise Power BI Report Server.
I have created and published a report that I want to embed in a web page,
then I set up a scheduled data refresh in the power bi portal to be once every minute,
then I embedded the report in an iFrame just like this documentation explains.
However, I want to refresh the data visually (the data that appears on the report) just like what the power bi refresh button does (see pic to understand what button I'm referring to)

However, the embed link (which we put in the iFrame) does not show this button, is there a way to trigger the refresh every specific time interval (every hour or minute for example) so that the new data appears?

You need to have a tool that can refresh your pbirs. Mo's of the time we use a navigator extension.
I recommend to use this chrome extension for that : https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/full-screen-auto-refresh/haebljcbppijaghbfigaiegljbiicllh

AKEAmazan, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate how it solves the problem in the answer itself.
